# $sql variable declaration error

Tags: php, sql, web, syntax-error

I cannot understand why xampp gives me an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Permanent\edstul.php on line 31

Line 31 is this :

```
if($_POST){

//update the record if the form was submitted
  $sql="UPDATE users SET pass='$_POST['pass']',fname='$_POST['fname']',lname='$_POST['lname']',mi='$_POST['mi']',age='$_POST['age']',course='$_POST['course']',yearlevel='$_POST['yearlevel']'
    WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

  if(mysql_query($sql)){
    //this will be displayed when the query was successful
    echo "<div>Record was edited.</div>";
  }else{
    die("SQL: " . $sql . " >> ERROR: " . mysql_error());
  }
}
```

I cannot figure it out.I really hate declaring sql syntax because it doesn't have debugging.

Comment: Do not use deprecated `mysql_* API. use `mysqli_*` or pdo. And also use prepared statement. That is safer and much more readable.

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes in your $_POST variables. `$_POST['pass']` => `$_POST[pass]`

Comment: Better yet; pre-define your variables, sanitize your inputs; use prepared statement.

Comment: @ScapeGoat [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php)

Comment: If you're going to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on one, do it for all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If you're going to use mysql_real_escape_string on one, dont do it at all.

Comment: @Loko Prepared statements; it's the way to go ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Im not using prepared statements myself but yeah I would agree it's probably the best way to go.

Comment: **Building SQL statements with outside variables makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.** Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like "O'Malley", will blow up your query. Learn about parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) has many detailed examples. See also http://bobby-tables.com/php for alternatives & explanation of the danger.

Answer (score 1):

You have some PHP concatenation errors, try with this :

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET pass='". $_POST['pass'] . "',
      fname='" .     $_POST['fname'] . "',
      lname='" .     $_POST['lname'] . "',
      mi='" .        $_POST['mi'] . "',
      age='" .       $_POST['age'] . "',
      course='" .    $_POST['course'] . "',
      yearlevel='" . $_POST['yearlevel'] . "'
      WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
```

Comment: and then you'd still have a problem with sql injections and you'd stil use the deprecated mysql_* extension. But yes, this will fix the _immediate_, the syntax error

Comment: Right answer  but you should mention that OP shouldn't use mysql_* function as it is deprecated +1